# Redirect all deeplinks to new domain with slight change in all URL's

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, http-status-code-301

I am trying to redirect all pages of DomainA to DomainB but with a slight change in the URL structure.

For example:

I need to redirect:

> http://www.domaina.com/cars/fast-motors ->
>   http://www.domainb.com/vehicles/fast-cars
>   http://www.domaina.com/cars/slow-motors ->
>   http://www.domainb.com/vehicles/slow-cars
>   http://www.domaina.com/cars/red-motors ->
>   http://www.domainb.com/vehicles/red-cars
>   http://www.domaina.com/cars/pink-motors ->
>   http://www.domainb.com/vehicles/pink-cars

I can manage to redirtect allurls to new domain like this:

> RewriteEngine on  RewriteRule ^cars/(.*)$
>   http://www.domainb.com/vehicles/$1 [R=301,L]

But I cant work out how to change the last word. theres thousands of these urls so i cant manually do a list of 301s. I basically need to redirect all urls to new domain but switch `/cars/` to `/vehicles/` and `-motors` to `-cars`.

Any help appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this in your `.htaccess` file :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^cars/(.*)-motors/? http://www.domainb.com/vehicles/$1-cars [R=302,L]
```

Change `[R=302]` for `[R=301]` when test work well.